# Using post install script in Trialforce

Tags: postinstall, trial

My company is provisioning trials using Trialforce. What I need to do is write a post install script which will make an API callout to a third party API and insert a new record in custom setting as soon as the trial is provisioned.

Now I went through the post install script info on this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=apex_post_install_script.htm&language=en_US

and it says in the Notes that **"You can’t run a post install script in a new trial organization provisioned using Trialforce. The script only runs when a subscriber installs your package in an existing organization."**

Is there another way besides a install script which will do the same job? Or is there a way to make a post install script run in a trial?

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a "start here" page where the installer clicks some button to provision the org? You can't trigger on user for login times etc. so I think that'd be your only option. Of course you could remove the click and do any provisioning the page's `action` parameter.

Comment: I did not understand, you want me to put a welcome page with a controller which will do the job?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the only way you'd be able to do it really. Or have a scheduled job perhaps, though not sure if they can be scheduled automatically without an install script.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can redirect them to a vf page after the trial is provisioned? Would be a big help. Thanks.

Comment: You could add a tab for the Visualforce page and then set that to be their default tab I think... it's been a while since I tried it.

Comment: but will this tab open everytime they log in? cause i want this function (the api call populating custom setting) to take place only once, that is when they login the first time.